# Only window close event in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I want to avoid delete cookies when I refresh the page. However If I close the window cookie should get delete.
Currently cookies getting deleted when I perform any of above two actions (Reload and Close).
Please let me know How Can I save my cookie on refresh the page.

I tried this :

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
  $.cookie('music_play' , 0,{path:'/bespoke/public'});
  $.removeCookie('music_title',{path:'/bespoke/public'});
  $.removeCookie('artist_name',{path:'/bespoke/public'});
});
```

Comment: If you only want data to last as long as the session why are you using cookies? Use `sessionStorage` as it's *exactly* what is was designed for.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan basically I want to perform a task that should be run when window close, But it is happening on both way reloading and closing